# DirectShow API MediaInfo field from Source Filter

Tags: c++, winapi, metadata, directshow

I want to extract information from MediaInfo section of Source Filter (to be more specific language field). How do I do that? None of the interfaces seem to support it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You will need to check LAVSplitter to see if it exposes language and, if yes, in what way exactly. I don't see language related code [here](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/blob/master/demuxer/LAVSplitter/OutputPin.h) for example.

Comment: You should check MediaInfo project.

Comment: There are multiple ways to extract language related information, including even stock Media Foundation APIs in Windows, however it does not seem to be an unknown interface in DirectShow which you expected to find. More to that, standard APIs in Windows don't even have support for MKV so you are looking for capability of third party extension component.

Comment: My point is if GraphStudio can bring up that information it means that it somehow retrieves that through DirectShow api, isn't it? And if so, what is the proper way to do that? Or it uses something else but DirectShow (which i doubt).

Comment: I'm not sure if GraphStudio is the one displaying that property list, it might be the decoder/splitter.

Comment: @mbaros: GraphStudioNext [literally executes MediaInfo application here](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/blob/master/src/MediaInfo.cpp#L7) and then presents the output in that property page. It has nothing to do with DirecShow interfaces.